# Proxy for automated browsing on mobile networks

Tags: proxy, ip-address, mobile-devices

I am interested in building a website scanner which needs to act as if it is a user agent on a mobile network (e.g. Verizon LTE connection in the US, Movistar LTE connection in Spain, etc.)

Aside from purchasing a sim card, are there any paid services or other verified techniques for connecting to a mobile network or otherwise getting your hands on an IP address block of theirs?

The point here is to have websites recognize that the requester's IP address belongs to a mobile carrier and observe the resulting behavior.

Comment: Why would you not just use a mobile device emulator or are you trying to test their network?

Comment: Yep, it's being on the network that is important.

Comment: then you need a sim card